# how to add words before line on all the scripts in current folder

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

under /home/scrript , we have 187 bash scripts
all the scripts have the following line:

```
kill -PIPE $PID
```

we want to add the following words before this line on all the scripts as the following

```
[[ $KILL_STATUS = YES ]] && kill -PIPE $PID
```

the reason for that is to avoid editing of each script  , and use Linux commands as sed to do in one shoot on all the scripts,

Comment: http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/insert-line-before-or-after-pattern.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ for i in /home/scrript/*; do sed -i 's/kill -PIPE $PID/[[ $KILL_STATUS = YES ]] \&\& kill -PIPE $PID/' "$i"; done
```

## Explanation

- `for i in /home/scrript/*; do FOO; done`: repeat for all files in `/home/scrript`. N.B. depending on your shell configuration this might skip dot files.
- `sed -i 's/kill -PIPE $PID/[[ $KILL_STATUS = YES ]] \&\& kill -PIPE $PID/' "$i"`: for each file (`"$i"`), replace "in-place" (`sed -i`), replacing `kill -PIPE $PID` with `[[ $KILL_STATUS = YES ]] \&\& kill -PIPE $PID`. (N.B. you need to escape the `&` as they have a special meaning otherwise.